# NotificationCompat difficulties in Koitlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I've been trying to follow
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded
in order to create a media notification. My SDK target is 21+.

I got a basic notification working but when I got to doing the media one I've had this problem:

```
import android.support.v4.app.!NotificationCompat!
import android.support.v4.media.!app!.NotificationCompat as MediaNotificationCompat
```

The two exclamation marked items (NotificationCompat and app) turn red in the editor and I can't use them :(
What do I need to do to get to the media style?

Notes:
I have this implementation `"com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0"` in my application build filee
It's underlined suggesting I move to androidx but I don't think that's an option?

Comment: "I don't think that's an option?" -- why not?

Comment: I had a quick go but couldn't work out the details. If you can advise that'd be great - a working androidx answer is acceptable

Comment: [This sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/tree/vFINAL/PayAttention) is pretty much my only current one in Kotlin using `NotificationCompat`, specifically the AndroidX edition. You might see how I have the dependencies and imports set up and see if you can adapt your project to match.

Comment: I can get that working, the difficulty is in accessing the `MediaNotificationCompat.MediaStyle()` that's not available on the libraries you've included

Comment: `NotificationCompat.MediaStyle` appears to be in `androidx.media:media`. Try adding `implementation "androidx.media:media:1.1.0"` to your dependencies.

Comment: Thank you! If you'd like some delicious reputation then add an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak for where the old Android Support edition of `NotificationCompat.MediaStyle` might be hiding. In AndroidX, you can find it in [the `androidx.media:media` artifact](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/media/media/). Right now, the latest stable version is `1.1.0`, so you can add:

```
implementation "androidx.media:media:1.1.0"
```

to your `dependencies` to pull that in.